# How to create dynamic labels in qt creator using C++?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Currently I have created label in ui form that contain database values.I want to retrieve all values from database to label dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

the following piece of code does something like this, but it assumes that you already have a table widget in the form to store all the widgets which will be created. The variable `i` loops over the records, and do not forget to set the row count of the table widget to the one you require. `<YOURSTUFF>` is the content (text) you want to put in the labels' text.

```
    QLabel* t = new QLabel(<YOURSTUFF>, this);
    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, 0, t);
```

Otherwise the following answer [Qt Creating layouts and adding widgets to layouts dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790454/qt-creating-layouts-and-adding-widgets-to-layouts-dynamically) has more information.

(I understood from your question that you want to dynamically create labels)